# No wifi network on Ubuntu. But working well on Windows on same laptop

Tags: networking, wireless

I am new to Ubuntu and recently switch on it. My wired internet works well. But I do not see any wifi network shown. I have gone to see on additional drivers to check if I am missing wireless driver but it doesn't show anything. Would installing new copy of Ubuntu help ?

edit here is the detail when i performed the following command: s**udo lshw -C network**

```
*-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: AR9287 Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express)
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:08:00.0
       logical name: wlp8s0
       version: 01
       serial: 18:f4:6a:d1:ab:69
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath9k driverversion=4.4.0-31-generic firmware=N/A ip=192.168.0.102 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
   resources: irq:17 memory:f1000000-f100ffff
```

Comment: Installing ubuntu again would not help but do you know what the chipset the wireless card is, this would be extremely helpful to know.

Comment: @ianorlin, I have wifi built in laptop intact same wifi on same laptop is working on window.

Comment: @DeepakPundir Ianorlin is asking what model of wireless card you have.

Comment: @wjandrea and here is the detail configuration:broadband=yes driver =ath9k. I hope that is what you are asking

Comment: @ianorlin i updated the details of my driver. see the edits in my question

Comment: @DeepakPundir Can you please edit your question and give us the output of  `rfkill list all`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello guys I simply install new copy of Ubuntu and it worked